Churn count over period
I have a sql query that counts churn but only for indicated (static) date_range and only for one week only. I want to update this query so it shows churn and retention for how many subscribers started their subscription in a particular week and how many has remained active in the following 6 weeks.
WITH 
date_range AS (
  SELECT DATE('2020-11-01') AS start_date,
         DATE('2020-11-08') AS end_date
),

start_account AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id
  FROM datatable subs
  INNER JOIN date_range AS dateRange 
  ON subs.subscription_start <= dateRange.start_date
  AND (subs.subscription_end > dateRange.start_date OR subs.subscription_end IS NULL)
),

end_accounts AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT user_pseudo_id
  FROM datatable subs 
  INNER JOIN date_range AS dateRange
  ON subs.subscription_start <= dateRange.end_date
  AND (subs.subscription_end > dateRange.end_date OR subs.subscription_end IS NULL)
),

churned_accounts AS (
  SELECT start.user_pseudo_id
  FROM start_account start
  LEFT OUTER JOIN end_accounts e 
  ON start.user_pseudo_id = e.user_pseudo_id
  WHERE e.user_pseudo_id IS NULL
),

start_count AS (
  SELECT COUNT(user_pseudo_id) AS n_start 
  FROM start_account
),

churn_count AS (
  SELECT COUNT(user_pseudo_id) AS n_churn 
  FROM churned_accounts
),

retained_count AS (
  SELECT COUNT(start.user_pseudo_id) AS n_retained
  FROM start_account start
  INNER JOIN end_accounts e 
  ON start.user_pseudo_id = e.user_pseudo_id
)

SELECT 
  start_count.n_start,
  churn_count.n_churn,
  start_count.n_start - churn_count.n_churn as retention
  
FROM churn_count, start_count;


Have tried using ai tools but none of them provided my needed results

you should provide sample data & desired result

Are you getting any error ?
